# Double-Click event not fired on IOS / Safari using Vaadin Grid

Tags: ios, safari, grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am creating a responsive web app using vaadin 23.1.0 and got a problem that the double click event is not fired on an Iphone with Safari. Never had any issues with that on other platforms.

The following code illustrates the problem. Button click works on IOS, doubleclick doesn't.

```
@PageTitle("IosTestView")
@Route(value = "IosTestView", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PermitAll
@Log4j2
public class IosTestView extends VerticalLayout {

    public IosTestView() {
        H2 h2 = new H2("IOS Test View");
        add(h2);
        List<String> testData = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
        Grid<String> testGrid = new Grid<>();
        testGrid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(a -> new Button("Go", b -> show(a))));
        testGrid.addColumn(a -> a);
        testGrid.addItemDoubleClickListener(a -> show(a.getItem()));
        testGrid.setItems(testData);
        add(testGrid);
    }

    private void show(String msg) {
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setPosition(Notification.Position.MIDDLE);
        notification.setText("Item : " + msg);
        notification.setDuration(5000);
        notification.open();
    }
}
```

No idea if there is an easy fix for this... but adding an extra button instead of using double click is not my favorite option...

Context Menu does work on IOS but I have no possibility to get the selected item - it's always null... seems to be the same issue...

Any help really welcome :-)

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same root cause as the other issue you described. The other issue was fixed in 23.1.1 - https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3296.

Please update to the current version to see if this fixes your problem as well.

Comment: I tried with the new version but the issue still exists... No doubleclick event on ios...

Comment: Please create a issue on GitHub with a minimal reproduce able example to get this investigated.

Comment: Done...: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3372